# proxmox - how to set recurring backup on nfs (external) disk?

Tags: proxmox

I have added an NFS backup to my Proxmox setup. From the console, I am able to view and create folders and files on /mnt/pre/backup/.

However, when I select Datacenter > Backup > Add, I only see "Local" in the Storage options, and not "Backup NFS Disk".

How can I create a recurring backup to the backup folder? Do I need to first create a backup locally and then copy/move it to /mnt/pre/backup?

Answer (score 0):

In Storage, under your NFS share, make sure you have selected "VZDump backup file".
Tripped me up for a few minutes too.